# EmberJS - rending out a table using a control helper inside an each block

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm having some trouble rending out a table using a control helper inside an each block. I have this ember app:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    rows: function(){
        return [
            Ember.Object.create({rowNum: 1}),
            Ember.Object.create({rowNum: 2}),
            Ember.Object.create({rowNum: 3})
        ]
    }.property()
});

App.RowController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    cols: function(){
        return [
            Ember.Object.create({colNum: 1}),
            Ember.Object.create({colNum: 2}),
            Ember.Object.create({colNum: 3})
        ]
    }.property()
});
```

And this template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application"> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
        </tr>
        {{#each row in rows}}
            {{#control "row" row}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{content.rowNum}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            {{/control}}
        {{/each}}
    </table>
    <hr />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
        </tr>
        {{#each row in rows}}
            {{#control "row" row}}
                <tr>
                    {{content.rowNum}}
                </tr>
            {{/control}}
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/charlieridley/AQ5gc/7/

The first table renders incorrectly displaying the last value for each iteration of the loop, but when I remove the
block from the renders the values correctly. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control helper was removed since 1.3.0-beta in [this commit](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/86eecd7ef7cdc7d2ea6f77b3a726b293292ec55d).
I recommend you to change to `render` view helper.

Your sample works using the render http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/2FvRh/